# Safecracker and RTE: html is double encoded or something?

Tags: safecracker, rte, v2.5.5

playing a bit with 2.5.5, I tried to create a Safecracker form with a RTE field. But when I edit an existing entry in this form, the HTML is displayed as HTML in the RTE box (see below), like if the content were double encoded or something.

[image]

How can I solve that?

[EDIT]: Little precision, this only happened with content saved from the control panel. Entries created or edited with the Safecracker form are correct (no html tags in the RTE).

[EDIT-BIS]: It is probably a bug, I posted it here: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19157

Comment: I solve this problem by not using RTE. Seriously, I have never had any luck with it. I know this isn't an answer, just how I avoid stuff like this.

Comment: @JustinKimbrell Yes I thought to use Wygman in the first place but I need to make a really cheap EE setup here. Maybe I should try Reedactor, but it's a bit frustrating.

Comment: Redactor.js is an awesome editor, I really enjoy it. I have been using Editor by DevDemon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been accepted by EllisLab as a bug: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19157